# Can anyone explain an example related to vague convergence?

Tags: measure-theory

Let {$X_n$} be a sequence of random variable and {$\mu_n$} be a sequence of measures induced by {$X_n$} such that $\mu_n(B) = \mathbf{P}(X_n^{-1}(B))$.

Suppose $X_n$ following a uniform distribution over interval ($c_n, c_n'$) where $c_n<0< c_n'$ and $c_n \rightarrow 0$, $c_n' \rightarrow 0$ and $X_n \rightarrow 0$ a.e.

Why might $\mu_n((a, 0))$ not converge at all or converge to any number between 0 and 1?

Note: this is from page 84 of Chung's A Course in Probability Theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uniform distribution's density function is drawn as a rectangle. As you decrease the length of the base $(c_n,c'_n)$, the height will adjust to keep the total area 1 (it will have the value $(c'_n - c_n)^{-1}$.) The probability $\mu_n((a,0))$ is (for $n$ large) the area of the rectangle on the left of the "y-axis"; you should be able to convince yourself that the area on the left can stay at some fixed $\alpha∈(0,1)$, or converge, or oscillate and not converge.

As a proof, we note that we can just compute the area as

$$ \mu_n((a,0)) = \frac{-c_n}{c'_n - c_n}$$
if you choose $c_n = -\alpha/n$ and $c'_n = 1/n$ then we see that

$$\mu_n((a,0)) = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1}$$
which can be made into any number in $(0,1)$.

As for an oscillating area, as a sketch, picture a case where $c_n$ and $c'_n$ take turns to get closer to 0, in the precise way that the ratios alternate between some values. I leave the details to you.

Comment: Can you explain the connection of this example and vague convergence?

Comment: @user1559897 don't know what that is? sorry